# bloquear meses a partir de una fecha dada

Tags: php, datepicker

tengo una duda tengo estos dos campos los cuales son date fur: fecha ultima regla y fpp: fecha probable de parto ahora lo que quiero lograr es que cuando ingrese una fecha en fur me bloquee 7 meses en adelante en fpp a partir de la fecha que ingrese en fpp. si alguien tiene un ejemplo se lo agradecería.

Comment: Si no agregas código es complicado saber a qué te refieres o como podemos ayudar. ¿qué tipo de datepicker es?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**aquí la solución**

```
<script>

function add_months(datestr, months) {
    var new_d = new Date(datestr);
    new_d.setMonth(new_d.getMonth() + months);
    return new_d;
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#fur').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: 10,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        onClose: function() {
            var date_add_m = add_months($('#fur').val(), 7);
            $('#fpp').pickadate({
                selectMonths: true,
                selectYears: 10,
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                disable: [{
                    from: new Date($('#fur').val()),
                    to: date_add_m
                }]
            })
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**los input**

```
<input type="text" name="fur"  id="fur"/>

<input type="text" name="fpp"  id="fpp">
```

Comment: yo desarrollo un sistema en el que se manejan datos de embarazadas y niños, y este tipo de información FUM (FUR) y FPP se manejan muy a menudo en el sistema. Una duda, por qué en tu caso a través de una FUM (FUR), restringes hasta 7 meses ?? Qué datos es ese que el usuario puede seleccionar en un periodo de 7 meses a partir de la FUM (FUR) ??

Comment: para calcular la fecha probable del parto recuerda que hay niños que nacen 7 mesinos pero bueno el cliente lo pidió así y uno tiene que hacer lo que diga el cliente.

Comment: "El cliente siempre tiene la razón", pero bueno teniendo la FUR tu sistema puede calcular la FPP sin que el usuario tenga que intervenir, recuerda fecha probable de parto, sumándole 280 días. Otra cosa sería la fecha real del parto; es solo una sugerencia.

Comment: si te entiendo pero es que el lo quiere así, es como decir que el mismo quiere poner la fecha a partir de los 7 meses es algo ilógico pero bueno cada quien tiene su idea

Comment: pues es como digo, el cliente tiene la razón. Gracias.